# Powerpoint 2016: how can I change master for a slide without messing up formatting?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, master

I have a deck with a slide master. I duplicated the master and made very minor changes to the copy. Basically, removed a word in a marker that sits in one of the corners of each slide. More precisely, the master contains about 10 different slides and so I made the same change for each of them in the master copy. However, when I changed the master for one of the slides, it messed up the formatting of the slide. The layout is pretty basic: a title area at the top then two text areas side by side with some bulleted lists in each area. Still, those lists got all out of whack. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Here's what I did:

1. Copied the master (as described [**here**](https://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/themes/2013/duplicate-slide-master.html) )
2. Renamed masters into "Main Master" and "Alternative Master" (as described [**here**](https://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/themes/2013/add-rename-slide-master.html) )
3. All slides were initially Main
4. Changed one slide's master from "Main" to "Alt" (as described [**here**](https://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/themes/2013/applying-slide-masters-individual-slides.html) )

**Expected behavior:** the changed slide should not change at all except for the difference between the two masters which, as described above, was a difference in one short word in a marker that's a text field in the corner.

**What I got:** the formatting of the slide changed significantly. For example, items in bulleted lists became misaligned.

Comment: Can you show us screenshots, before and after? Of both the slides themselves and of the layouts that govern them. And in modifying the layout or master, did you delete and/or add placeholders or simply modify the existing placeholders?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Sorry can't share :-(. I duplicated the original master, then modified every slide placeholder in the copy by editing the marker word that differed between the two.